# Contact page template - redirect to 'thank you page' not working

Tags: forms, wordpress, email, contacts

I'm trying to submit a form via custom page template but the problem is that it only works with `form action="<?php the_permalink() ?>"` and I need the form to be submitted and redirected to something like this `form action="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/message-sent?id=<?php the_ID() ?>"`

Full code:

```
<?php 
$emailError = '';
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

            $email = trim($_POST['email']);



                //setup self email address
                $emailTo = $email; 


            $subject = "[reminder] Don't forget to download " . get_the_title();
            $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
            $headers = 'From: Myemail reminders <no-reply@xyz.com>' . "\r\n";
            wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
            $emailSent = true;

} ?>




<section class="box grid_9 list_posts">
<div class="inner">
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="contact-form clearfix">
                            <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
<div class="thanks">
<?php _e('Thanks, your email was sent successfully.', 'framework') ?>
</div>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)) { ?>
<p class="error"><?php _e('Sorry, an error occured.', 'framework') ?>

                                <?php } ?>






<form action="<?php the_permalink()?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
<ul class="contactform">



<li>
                                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" class="required requiredField email" required="required" />
                                        </li>

<li class="buttons">

                                            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                                            <input type="submit" value="Remind Me!"></input>
                                        </li>
</ul></form>






                            <?php } ?></div>
</div>
</div>
                    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<div id="post-0" <?php post_class() ?>>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e('Error 404 - Not Found', 'framework') ?></h1>

</div>
                <?php endif; ?></div>
</section>
```

I got no php errors in log, page is redirected successfully, but no email is sent. When using the_permalink, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting the form data to a different script, make sure the code for (validating the input and) sending the email is in that very file.

Otherwise, your URL `/message-sent` might rewrite to a completely different script and the script with the above code isn't involved at all once the submit button gets clicked.

Did that held you? Feel free, to ask, if my wording is incomprehensible or if my description isn't clear to you

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it right, but the validation code should go to /message-sent page? Sorry for not understanding I'm still learning php language.

Comment: Whatever you but into the form's `action` attribute will be the URL to visit once the form gets submitted. In your case, that would be `/message-sent`. And that should be the place (the script) to validate the input and sent the email.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for quick and easy to understand response. Now everything is working just fine.

Comment: But I would actually suggest another way to do it. Sent the form to the permalink. That way you can keep anything regarding the form together and in one place. And then perform a HTTP Redirect to a `/thank-you` page if the email was sent successfully. That way, you are also a little more secure in terms of browser refresh problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to put "**.php**" at the end of your `/message-sent?id=xxx` file, i.e `/message-sent.php?id=xxx`?

Another thought: It is always a good idea to filter the user input, because you will receive a lot of spam, put some sort of CAPTCHA validation code and sanitize/validate the whole user input text, i.e. every text, which comes from input fields of your form.

For email:

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

For name and comments:

```
$name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$comments = filter_var(strip_tags($_POST['comments']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: It's not an issue as it is a wordpress page so it only works as '/message-sent?id=xxx'

Comment: the reason I didn't put any validation (except of HTML5 email field) is that it's going to be a reminder service for which will send an email to the address provided with necessary information so people won't forget to come back later and download the file.